# SELECT with unique values based on a subset of columns for MySQL, H2 and DB2

Tags: mysql, sql, db2, h2

I have the following query which works fine in **MySQL**:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
```

that allows me to select all results from `mytable` that are unique (distinct) based on the values of multiple columns `col2, col3, col4, col5, col6`.

Unfortunately that query does not work for **H2** and **DB2** (it gives the *...must be in the GROUP BY list...* error) and I'm looking for a generic and also **efficient** alternative.

I have also tried the following one:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5, t1.col6
FROM mytable t1
JOIN (SELECT t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5, t2.col6
        FROM mytable t2
        GROUP BY t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5, t2.col6) x 
        ON x.col1 = t1.col1
            AND x.col2 = t1.col2
            AND x.col3 = t1.col3
            AND x.col4 = t1.col4
            AND x.col5 = t1.col5
            AND x.col6 = t1.col6;
```

but it was VERY slow (tried with a Docker MariaDB local instance), especially because I will use that `SELECT` inside a `INSERT INTO ...` query so I need something efficient.

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: The result from the second query is *not* equivalent to the result from the first query. That first query only "works fine" in MySQL if a non-standard MySQL-specific extension is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does **not** work fine in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
```

Older versions of MySQL happen to support this syntax, but it is broken  syntax.  The `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses are not consistent.  Happily MySQL has not supported this syntax (using the default configuration) in versions released in the past few years.

If you want one row per combination, then use window functions or some similar method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 order by col2) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: wow cool it works thank you! Is `order by` required or suggested somehow?

Comment: @Briston12, some DBMS require an order by clause, others do not. I tested at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=808fd69bd43133fd67a0a66112dc72d5 and SQL-server 2019 and Oracle 18c requires an order by.  Db2, MariaDB, MySQL, SQLlite, Postgres works fine without order by

Comment: An ORDER BY can help the statement be deterministic. I.e. if you `ORDER BY col1` then if you have tow or more rows with the same col2-6 values, you will get the row with he lowest col1 value with `seqnum = 1`